# PIN forgotten.no option of "forgot password"

Tags: password, locked-out

Using oneplus one (not rooted). PIN forgotten. no option of "forgot password". Android device manager doesn't locate my device. cellular data is on. doesn't connect to the wifi automatically. din't know whethere USB debugging is on. need to recover 1-2 important apps but locked out. Please HELP!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forgot Oneplus One pin. How to enable usb debugging?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/118819/forgot-oneplus-one-pin-how-to-enable-usb-debugging)

Answer (score -1):

If you have rooted your phone, boot into recovery and delete following files:

```
/data/system/locksettings.db
/data/system/gesture.key
```

Then reboot.

If not, you would have to find a way to root your device without loosing your data.
Maybe `fastboot oem unlock` is the key for that.

And this might be the same question: [Forgot Oneplus One pin. How to enable usb debugging?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/118819/forgot-oneplus-one-pin-how-to-enable-usb-debugging)

Comment: Rooting section is not relevant to OP since it is mentioned in the question: "*Using oneplus one (**not rooted**)*", so naturally, only Cyanogen recovery would be there as a stock recovery and it doesn't grant  shell access, forget about root access. // `fastboot oem unlock` wipes data partition while OP wants to recover something. So it is not useful either.